# why does windows phone 7 NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable() return true when airplane mode is enabled

Tags: networking, windows-phone-7

i have a windows phone 7 app that communicates with a web service.  i've been looking at other questions that answer how to detect if there is a network connection.  I thought 'fantastic' i've found my answer.

However, the call to NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable() always returns true.  It returns true in the emulator, it returns true on a device with airplane mode enabled, it returns true on device when airplane mode is disabled.

as further details, i have the latest beta SDK (7.1 - mango) running.

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Are you debugging with the phone plugged into the PC? If so, the phone will use your PC's internet connection.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This method will always return true in debug mode.

The emulator is always connected to the host PC and so always has a connection.

If debugging on an actual device, the USB connection is a connection and so there is always a connection there.

The only way to test this method is on an actual device when not connected to a PC.